# Nominative or accusative case for "ein Morgen"

Tags: grammar, grammatical-case, time

To say "one morning in May I flew to London", should I say

> (a) Ein Morgen im Mai bin ich nach London geflogen.

or

> (b) Einen Morgen ...

or other possibilities?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have a when-indication then it is neither "ein Morgen" nor "einen Morgen" but "eines Morgens" or "an einem Morgen". - Eines Morgens wachte Herr K. auf und fand, dass er ein käfer war. (Adapted from Kafka, The Metamorphosis).

By the way, the word Morgen has different meanings:

- **morgen**, adverb, is the next day
- **morgens**, adverb, means in the morning
- **eines Morgens** is an adverb-group, meaning on the morning of a certain day (a when-indication)
- **ein Morgen Land** is a measure of area. What a farmer can plough during one morning/the first half of a day.

Comment: The last bullet point is not to be confused with *Morgenland* (*the East* as in *the middle/far East*)

Answer (score 2):

I would say this is 2. case (Genitiv)

> "Eines Morgens im Mai flog ich nach London"

So you have an indefinite article on "morning" because you don't name a specific date and a question like "Q: Wessen Morgen im Mai? A: Eines." That expression is than followed by a dependent clause.

I think it could also have something to do with temporal adverbs

You can find a similar example on [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Morgen_Tageszeit_Masz_Osten) in the examples list.

Comment: There are adverbs of time in German having the form of a genitive. But it is not a normal genitive, it is an "adverbial genitive", a when-indication in the form of a genitive. One might explain: When was it? - It was the time of a (certain) morning. Es war die Zeit irgendeines Morgens.